# Suggest comment "thread" deletion

Tags: feature-request, comments

Often there are discussions between two or three people in comments - and most are finished without moving or simply become obsolete quickly due to edits in the answer/question.

Of course one could now delete the now-useless comments but with replies from other people it would become pretty confusing. An easy way to avoid this would be the possibility to mark a group of comments for atomic deletion. Unlike the current comment flagging system this should only have one reason, "obsolete", and high-rep people should see those flags so they are likely to vote for/against deletion of the discussion.

Instead of creating a public vote it could also be done in a way that it is only shown to the people involved (i.e. the authors of the comments) and only one of them can suggest such a deletion. With all authors agreeing these comments would automatically be deleted.

Comment: Comments aren't worth that much effort, to be honest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I've done is to flag one of the comments and use the "other reason" field.

> This comment and the 6 following it are part of an obsolete conversation.

A moderator can then delete the bunch in one swell foop.

Comment: That would indeed work but I think moderators have something better to do than deleting tons of obsolete comments.

Comment: _::foop::_ I wish deletion made that noise :D

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't, @TimManishEarth?

Comment: @ThiefMaster You'd be surprised, after all the, system warns us when there are 20 or more comments on a poast.  I'm perfectly ok with this when users tell us there's an obsolete conversation going on and we can wipe the comments.  But please be *specific* about which comments can go.  Also, in large cases, it might be better to flag the *post* and not the comment.

Comment: @casperOne: do you put butter on your poast?

Comment: Most cases are not that bad - at least the discussions I'm involved in are usually around 5 comments long - but still, often obsolete after some edits.

Comment: what if they decline