# Support cascading deletion of comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

Common scenario:

1. Post a question.
2. Get a comment almost immediately about some error, ambiguity, error, or missing info.
3. Update the question.
4. Post a response comment that you fixed it.
5. The original poster deletes his comment (to reduce clutter).
6. Delete your comment.

The requested feature is to allow the step 4 comment to be linked to the step 2 comment, such that when the step 4 comment is deleted, the step 4 comment is automatically deleted.

Comment: [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/discussions-flat-or-threaded.html) and [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/12/web-discussions-flat-by-design.html) (both by the co-founder of Stack Overflow)

Comment: Related: [Suggest comment "thread" deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132274) [Can we have threaded comments on answer comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31028) [What's the best way to request a comment-thread cleanup by the participants?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135035)

Comment: @Doorknob: Good point and thanks for the references. I changed the request to remove the nesting. The linking and cascading delete are really what I'm after.

Comment: Related scenario regarding an answer and comments that became obsolete as an atomic unit: [Atomic comment removal after edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202685/167867)

Answer (score 8):

I think you've got a good idea that might suffer from wandering too close to an established minefield.

Threaded/nested/hierarchical comments have been brought up and shot down repeatedly.  ***Attempt no landing there.***

Allowing comment dependency **without any visual difference** is potentially a new and useful idea that sounds like the heart of your request.

It would be useful to be able to make a comment **dependent on another** so that **if it's deleted my comment is too**.  The comment thread would still look exactly the same, the only difference would be cascading deletes.  That way comments can be more easily cleaned up without either leaving a mess of unmoored replies or asking a mod for help.